# PHP Move_uploaded_file not moving my file to directory

Tags: php, upload

I am making an image uploading feature for a program I am developing however I cant seem to get move_uploaded_file to actually move my file and I am not sure why.

I am receiving the form data as I can see the data when I use the print_r function `print_r($_FILES)`

My directory struct is as follows
`root->app->lib->uploadCode.php` and `root->app->images`

I dont get any errors.
I am running this on ubuntu 16.04 with php7 installed

Here is my code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(!empty($_FILES['newImage']['name']))
{
    $fname = $_FILES['newImage']['name'];
    $fext = explode(".",$fname);
    $sex = array("jpg", "jpeg", "JPG", "JPEG", "png", "PNG");//Supported extensions
    //Check if file extension supported
    $extRes = array_intersect($fext, $sex);//Checks to see if file uploaded extension exists in the supported extension array
    if(count($extRes) == 1)
    {
        print_r($_FILES);
        $name = $_FILES['newImage']['name'];
        $ext = end($fext);
        $tmp = $_FILES['newImage']['tmp_name'];
        $path = '/../images/';
        $newName = uniqid().".".$ext;
        /*if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$newName))
        {
            echo "uploaded";
        }
        else
            {
                echo "not uploaded";
                echo $path.$newName;
            }*/

        move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$newName);
    }
    elseif(count($extRes) > 1)
        {//More than just one file extension was found possibly something like image.png.jpg
            echo 02;
        }
        else
            {// Nothing was found so wrong file type was used
                echo 01;
            }
}else
    {//Do if no image was uploaded
        echo 00;
    }
```

`

Comment: btw, all your `00, 01, 02` are octals; use quotes for them.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the opening slash from `$path = '/../images/';` or set the full path, e.g. `/home/username/images/` for example

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I did try removing the starting slash and just having `../images/` I also tried the full path but still no luck

Comment: If you set `$path` to be the full path and then `echo` this then what do you see?

Comment: At first I thought it might be a permissions issue but I set the directory to cmod -R 777 and I used chown to grant a non root user permissions also

Comment: When I set the full path this is what I get when I echo out just the path `/var/www/html/project/app/images/`

Comment: Seems OK then ... like you suggested, must be a permissions issue

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue.

I had to do the following to my www/html directory.

`sudo chown -R username:www-data /var/www/html/`
 `sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/`
 `sudo chmod g+s /var/www/html`
Once I ran those commands I was able to upload